# cocos2d-js: How to load a JSON file

Tags: json, cocos2d-js

How can I load a JSON file from the local filesystem into a javascript object?

Something similar to jQuery:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    // data contains javascript object
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [answered in the official forums](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-load-config-data-from-json-file-in-helloworld/14977/3?u=zippolag), you can make a call to `cc.loader.loadJson`:

```
cc.loader.loadJson("res/example.json", function(error, data){
    cc.log(data); //data is the json object
});
```

The function that you pass as parameter will be called back when the file finishes loading.

Answer (score 0):

Researching this I found following (not complete) solution:

```
var loadJSON = function(url, cb) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState==3 && xhr.status==200) {
            cb(null,JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
};

// read json file with words
loadJSON("res/words/dewords.words.json", function(err, text) {
    if( !err ) {
        muprisLayer.words = text;           
    }
});
```