# Cocos2d: compile JS code, with remote server communication, to native platforms

Tags: cocos2d-js

**Setup**:

- cocos2d-x-3.7
- created project with: "cocos new MyGame -l js -p org.cocos2d.mygame"
- i will write the code in Javascript

**Question:**
What is the way to do server communication from javascript code(e.g. AJAX).
It should work also, after compiling to native plattforms
e.g. "cocos run -p mac"

**Maybe with:**

```
cc.loader.loadJson("http://REMOTE_URL_HERE", function(error, data){ cc.log(data);});
```

But I get:
"Get data from file http://REMOTE_URL_HERE failed"
Any Ideas?
Thanks

I found:
[cocos2d-js: How to load a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359297/cocos2d-js-how-to-load-a-json-file)
but this is only for loading local files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //xhr.statusText;
        //xhr.responseText
};
xhr.send();
```